# Find replace all in DOM error

Tags: javascript, replace, find

I am trying to find all occurrences of `?sid=XXXXXXXXXX`and replace them with `blank`. I have this same code working elsewhere on my page finding and replacing a phone number (for example).

I am executing the following command:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/?sid=XXXXXXXXXX/g, '');
```

A sample of the HTML it is supposed to edit is:

```
<a href="/faqs/?sid=XXXXXXXXXX">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /?sid=XXXXXXXXXX/: Nothing to repeat
```

I cannot understand why it works for other strings and not this one. I understood that the above is basically treating the DOM contents as a long text string and thus the find and replace should operate like it does on the phone number example. What am I missing? Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: As is often the case, the error message tells you quite precisely what the problem is, if you read it closely and/or search for it. A search for "regular expression nothing to repeat" will bring up dozens of posts on SO and elsewhere where a "quantifier" (`*`, `{}`, `?`, `+`) is misplaced, or was not escaped when it was intended to be treated as a regular character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't replace the contents of body element using innerHTML replace, it can have side effects like can remove any registered event handlers etc.... instead target and replace the required

```
var as = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="?sid=XXXXXXXXXX"]');
for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    var href = as[i].getAttribute('href');
    as[i].setAttribute('href', href.replace(/\?sid=XXXXXXXXXX/g, ''));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e33tc8uh/)

Comment: For better support, why not use `getElementsByTagName` and then add an `if` to check the attribute. A small change for significantly higher support

Comment: @vihan1086 I think it is supported in IE8+ so should be fine in most cases

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for the reply. I have implemented your suggestion instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `?` in your regex:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\?sid=XXXXXXXXXX/g, '');
```

`?` is a special character in regular expressions so if you want to match them you need to make sure you escape them first. [View this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters) to see a complete list of characters.

Comment: You're welcome @TheRealPapa! Consider marking my answer as correct if it solves the problem. Cheers!